# How to get bit rate of audio file in Blackberry/j2me

Tags: audio, blackberry

I want to retrive the bit rate of an audio file for the purpose of spliting a raw byte information of an audio file at a particular second of complete length of file.Can any one suggest the way to get the bit rate for an audio file in Blackberry or j2me?